# The graceful way to handle filters depending on the request url or routing service id

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I need to determin if the API is being requested should be filtered by a specific filter?

The common sense is to split the request url by slash to get the exactly interface and then compare it to the url lists preset, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serviceId` property in `RequestContext` in your filter and check it in your filter's `shouldFilter()` method something like the below. If your filter is `pre` filter, it must have bigger value of filter order than the value of `PreDecorationFilater`. Currently it is 5.

```
@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    if ((ctx.get("serviceId") != null) && ctx.get("serviceId").equals("service_id_that_you_want_to_handle")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

One thing you should know is that if you are specifying url itself instead of using eureka, you should use `proxy` property in `RequestContext` instead of `serviceId`.

Comment: I don't know about `proxy`, but you should use the `RequestContext.getRouteHost()` method for full url's instead of `serviceId`.